# Error with using Bitmap class in project

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

Hi I am trying to divide the logic of my simple WPF program to projects in .NET. I created project with type Class Library. After i tried to use class Bitmap in class of project but validator find error
"The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Микола\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\dragNDrop\BusinessLogic\Util.cs"
How to solve this trouble?

P.S. Sorry i'm only started to studing .NET, and their types of Projects

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace BusinessLogic
{
    class Util
    {
        public Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap img, Rectangle cropArea)
        {
            Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
            return bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `using System.Drawing;`

Comment: i use `using System.Drawing;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Solution Explorer. In your project folder, right-click 'References'. Click 'Add reference'. In the list, check `System.Drawing`. Now the assembly reference is added to your project. Combined to the `using` line that you already have, the compiler should not complain anymore.